# paper-radio button does not update properly

Tags: data-binding, polymer, radio-group

I want to create a formular which, according to the chosen user type, displays different field.
For this, I have a radio group and some data-binding set on the `selected` property of this group.

```
<paper-radio-group id="newUserTypeRadio" selected="{{newUserType}}">
    <paper-radio-button name="admin">admin</paper-radio-button>    
    <paper-radio-button name="user">user</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="guest">guest</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

my listener:

```
listeners: { 
            "newUserTypeRadio.change": "userTypeForm"
        }
```

and the function, which is (for now) just a `console.log`

```
        userTypeForm: function () {
            console.log("user type : ", this.newUserType);
        }
```

SO yeah that's it. The problem is, when I first click on "Admin" radio button, the log says `undefined`, then I click on "guest", and the log shows "admin", etc... so the `selected` value is always the previous value, not the current one.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution implemented using `observer` instead of `listener`

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
<dom-module id="radio-group">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <paper-radio-group id="newUserTypeRadio" selected="{{newUserType}}">
      <paper-radio-button name="admin">admin</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="user">user</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button name="guest">guest</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'radio-group',
    properties: {
      newUserType: {
        type: String,
        observer: 'userTypeForm'
      }
    },
    userTypeForm: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("oldvalue:" + oldVal, ", current value:" + newVal, ", newUserType value:" + this.newUserType);
    }
  })
</script>


<radio-group></radio-group>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!! I'm still a beginner, can you explain me the difference between observer and listener in this case?